# Postgres - pg_upgrade 11 to 12 role "postgres" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-swarm, pg-upgrade

When trying to upgrade from 11 to 12 by using https://github.com/tianon/docker-postgres-upgrade - the following error pops up:

```
docker run --rm \
        -e PGUSER=$POSTGRES_USER \
        -e POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS="-U $POSTGRES_USER" \
        -v aip-pgs-data:/var/lib/postgresql/$OLD/data \
        -v aip-pg12-data:/var/lib/postgresql/$NEW/data \
        "tianon/postgres-upgrade:$OLD-to-$NEW"
```

LOGS:----

```
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                   ok

connection to database failed: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist

could not connect to source postmaster started with the command:
"/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_ctl" -w -l "pg_upgrade_server.log" -D "/var/lib/postgresql/11/data" -o "-p 50432 -b  -c listen_addresses='' -c unix_socket_permissions=0700 -c unix_socket_directories='/var/lib/postgresql'" start
Failure, exiting
```

Any idea why this is happening?  OR is that open bug.? what is the fix.?

Comment: What is $POSTGRES_USER set to?  Where is it getting set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, once i passed POSTGRES_USER as env, then it's working fine. thank you